# Optimize 128x128 to 256-bit multiply for Intel AVX[SIMD]

Tags: c++, simd, biginteger, avx, extended-precision

I'm trying to implement multiplication of 128 unsigned int on two 64 unsigned integers by Intel AVX. The problem is that non vectorised version works faster than hand-vectorised version.

Here is my test benchmark. On my laptop i got next results:

- AVX    - 5200
- NonAVX - 1600

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>

#include <emmintrin.h>
#include <immintrin.h>

constexpr uint32_t N        = 28u;
constexpr uint32_t X        = 64u;
constexpr uint32_t Y        = 32u;
constexpr uint32_t Z        = 128u;

constexpr uint32_t LOW[4]   = { 4294967295u, 0u, 4294967295u, 0u };
__m128i L                   = _mm_lddqu_si128( reinterpret_cast< __m128i const* >( LOW ) );

typedef union
{
    __m128i     x;
    uint32_t    u[4];
} 
__u128i;

static inline __attribute__((always_inline)) void multiply128x128( const uint32_t ABCD[4], const uint32_t EFGH[4], uint32_t OUT[2][4] ) noexcept
{

    __m128i IN = _mm_lddqu_si128( reinterpret_cast< __m128i const* >( EFGH ) );

    __m128i A  = _mm_set1_epi32( ABCD[0] );
    __m128i B  = _mm_set1_epi32( ABCD[1] );
    __m128i C  = _mm_set1_epi32( ABCD[2] );
    __m128i D  = _mm_set1_epi32( ABCD[3] );

    __m128i ED = _mm_mul_epu32( IN, D );
    __m128i EC = _mm_mul_epu32( IN, C );
    __m128i EB = _mm_mul_epu32( IN, B );
    __m128i EA = _mm_mul_epu32( IN, A );

    IN = _mm_srli_epi64( IN, 32 );

    __m128i FD = _mm_mul_epu32( IN, D );
    __m128i FC = _mm_mul_epu32( IN, C );
    __m128i FB = _mm_mul_epu32( IN, B );
    __m128i FA = _mm_mul_epu32( IN, A );

    __m128i FD_H = _mm_srli_epi64( FD, 32 );
    __m128i FD_L = _mm_and_si128 ( L, FD );

    __m128i FC_H = _mm_srli_epi64( FC, 32 );
    __m128i FC_L = _mm_and_si128 ( L, FC );

    __m128i FB_H = _mm_srli_epi64( FB, 32 );
    __m128i FB_L = _mm_and_si128 ( L, FB );

    __m128i FA_H = _mm_srli_epi64( FA, 32 );
    __m128i FA_L = _mm_and_si128 ( L, FA );

    __m128i ED_H = _mm_srli_epi64( ED, 32 );
    __m128i ED_L = _mm_and_si128 ( L, ED );

    __m128i EC_H = _mm_srli_epi64( EC, 32 );
    __m128i EC_L = _mm_and_si128 ( L, EC );

    __m128i EB_H = _mm_srli_epi64( EB, 32 );
    __m128i EB_L = _mm_and_si128 ( L, EB );

    __m128i EA_H = _mm_srli_epi64( EA, 32 );
    __m128i EA_L = _mm_and_si128 ( L, EA );

    __m128i SUM_FC_L_FD_H = _mm_add_epi64( FC_L, FD_H );
    __m128i SUM_FB_L_FC_H = _mm_add_epi64( FB_L, FC_H );
    __m128i SUM_FA_L_FB_H = _mm_add_epi64( FA_L, FB_H );

    __m128i SUM_EC_L_ED_H = _mm_add_epi64( EC_L, ED_H );
    __m128i SUM_EB_L_EC_H = _mm_add_epi64( EB_L, EC_H );
    __m128i SUM_EA_L_EB_H = _mm_add_epi64( EA_L, EB_H );

    __m128i SUM_FC_L_FD_H_ED_L           = _mm_add_epi64( SUM_FC_L_FD_H, ED_L );
    __m128i SUM_FB_L_FC_H_EC_L_ED_H      = _mm_add_epi64( SUM_FB_L_FC_H, SUM_EC_L_ED_H );
    __m128i SUM_FA_L_FB_H_EB_L_EC_H      = _mm_add_epi64( SUM_FA_L_FB_H, SUM_EB_L_EC_H );
    __m128i SUM_FA_H_EA_L_EB_H           = _mm_add_epi64( FA_H, SUM_EA_L_EB_H );

    __u128i SUM_FC_L_FD_H_ED_L_L;
            SUM_FC_L_FD_H_ED_L_L.x       = _mm_srli_epi64( SUM_FC_L_FD_H_ED_L, 32 );
            SUM_FC_L_FD_H_ED_L_L.x       = _mm_add_epi64 ( SUM_FC_L_FD_H_ED_L_L.x, SUM_FB_L_FC_H_EC_L_ED_H );

    __u128i SUM_FC_L_FD_H_ED_L_L_L;
            SUM_FC_L_FD_H_ED_L_L_L.x     = _mm_srli_epi64( SUM_FC_L_FD_H_ED_L_L.x, 32 );
            SUM_FC_L_FD_H_ED_L_L_L.x     = _mm_add_epi64 ( SUM_FC_L_FD_H_ED_L_L_L.x, SUM_FA_L_FB_H_EB_L_EC_H );

    __u128i SUM_FC_L_FD_H_ED_L_L_L_L;
            SUM_FC_L_FD_H_ED_L_L_L_L.x   = _mm_srli_epi64( SUM_FC_L_FD_H_ED_L_L_L.x, 32 );
            SUM_FC_L_FD_H_ED_L_L_L_L.x   = _mm_add_epi64 ( SUM_FC_L_FD_H_ED_L_L_L_L.x, SUM_FA_H_EA_L_EB_H );

    __u128i SUM_FC_L_FD_H_ED_L_L_L_L_L;
            SUM_FC_L_FD_H_ED_L_L_L_L_L.x = _mm_srli_epi64( SUM_FC_L_FD_H_ED_L_L_L_L.x, 32 );
            SUM_FC_L_FD_H_ED_L_L_L_L_L.x = _mm_add_epi64 ( SUM_FC_L_FD_H_ED_L_L_L_L_L.x, EA_H );

    OUT[0][0] = SUM_FC_L_FD_H_ED_L_L_L_L_L.u[0];
    OUT[0][1] = SUM_FC_L_FD_H_ED_L_L_L_L.u[0];
    OUT[0][2] = SUM_FC_L_FD_H_ED_L_L_L.u[0];
    OUT[0][3] = SUM_FC_L_FD_H_ED_L_L.u[0];

    OUT[1][0] = SUM_FC_L_FD_H_ED_L_L_L_L_L.u[2];
    OUT[1][1] = SUM_FC_L_FD_H_ED_L_L_L_L.u[2];
    OUT[1][2] = SUM_FC_L_FD_H_ED_L_L_L.u[2];
    OUT[1][3] = SUM_FC_L_FD_H_ED_L_L.u[2];
}

static inline void multiply128x128_1( const uint32_t ABCD[4], const uint32_t EFGH[4], uint32_t OUT[2][4] ) noexcept
{
    uint64_t ED = static_cast<uint64_t>( ABCD[3] ) * static_cast<uint64_t>( EFGH[0] );
    uint64_t EC = static_cast<uint64_t>( ABCD[2] ) * static_cast<uint64_t>( EFGH[0] );
    uint64_t EB = static_cast<uint64_t>( ABCD[1] ) * static_cast<uint64_t>( EFGH[0] );
    uint64_t EA = static_cast<uint64_t>( ABCD[0] ) * static_cast<uint64_t>( EFGH[0] );

    uint64_t FD = static_cast<uint64_t>( ABCD[3] ) * static_cast<uint64_t>( EFGH[1] );
    uint64_t FC = static_cast<uint64_t>( ABCD[2] ) * static_cast<uint64_t>( EFGH[1] );
    uint64_t FB = static_cast<uint64_t>( ABCD[1] ) * static_cast<uint64_t>( EFGH[1] );
    uint64_t FA = static_cast<uint64_t>( ABCD[0] ) * static_cast<uint64_t>( EFGH[1] );

    uint64_t SUM_FC_L_FD_H = ( FC & 0xFFFFFFFF ) + ( FD >> 32u );
    uint64_t SUM_FB_L_FC_H = ( FB & 0xFFFFFFFF ) + ( FC >> 32u );
    uint64_t SUM_FA_L_FB_H = ( FA & 0xFFFFFFFF ) + ( FB >> 32u );

    uint64_t SUM_EC_L_ED_H = ( EC & 0xFFFFFFFF ) + ( ED >> 32u );
    uint64_t SUM_EB_L_EC_H = ( EB & 0xFFFFFFFF ) + ( EC >> 32u );
    uint64_t SUM_EA_L_EB_H = ( EA & 0xFFFFFFFF ) + ( EB >> 32u );

    uint64_t SUM_FC_L_FD_H_ED_L         = SUM_FC_L_FD_H + ( ED & 0xFFFFFFFF );
    uint64_t SUM_FB_L_FC_H_EC_L_ED_H    = SUM_FB_L_FC_H + SUM_EC_L_ED_H;
    uint64_t SUM_FA_L_FB_H_EB_L_EC_H    = SUM_FA_L_FB_H + SUM_EB_L_EC_H;
    uint64_t SUM_FA_H_EA_L_EB_H         = SUM_EA_L_EB_H + ( FA >> 32u );

    uint64_t SUM_FC_L_FD_H_ED_L_L       = ( SUM_FC_L_FD_H_ED_L       >> 32u ) + SUM_FB_L_FC_H_EC_L_ED_H;
    uint64_t SUM_FC_L_FD_H_ED_L_L_L     = ( SUM_FC_L_FD_H_ED_L_L     >> 32u ) + SUM_FA_L_FB_H_EB_L_EC_H;
    uint64_t SUM_FC_L_FD_H_ED_L_L_L_L   = ( SUM_FC_L_FD_H_ED_L_L_L   >> 32u ) + SUM_FA_H_EA_L_EB_H;
    uint64_t SUM_FC_L_FD_H_ED_L_L_L_L_L = ( SUM_FC_L_FD_H_ED_L_L_L_L >> 32u ) + ( EA >> 32u );

    OUT[0][0] = SUM_FC_L_FD_H_ED_L_L_L_L_L;
    OUT[0][1] = SUM_FC_L_FD_H_ED_L_L_L_L;
    OUT[0][2] = SUM_FC_L_FD_H_ED_L_L_L;
    OUT[0][3] = SUM_FC_L_FD_H_ED_L_L;


    uint64_t GD = static_cast<uint64_t>( ABCD[3] ) * static_cast<uint64_t>( EFGH[2] );
    uint64_t GC = static_cast<uint64_t>( ABCD[2] ) * static_cast<uint64_t>( EFGH[2] );
    uint64_t GB = static_cast<uint64_t>( ABCD[1] ) * static_cast<uint64_t>( EFGH[2] );
    uint64_t GA = static_cast<uint64_t>( ABCD[0] ) * static_cast<uint64_t>( EFGH[2] );

    uint64_t HD = static_cast<uint64_t>( ABCD[3] ) * static_cast<uint64_t>( EFGH[3] );
    uint64_t HC = static_cast<uint64_t>( ABCD[2] ) * static_cast<uint64_t>( EFGH[3] );
    uint64_t HB = static_cast<uint64_t>( ABCD[1] ) * static_cast<uint64_t>( EFGH[3] );
    uint64_t HA = static_cast<uint64_t>( ABCD[0] ) * static_cast<uint64_t>( EFGH[3] );

    uint64_t SUM_HC_L_HD_H = ( HC & 0xFFFFFFFF ) + ( HD >> 32u );
    uint64_t SUM_HB_L_HC_H = ( HB & 0xFFFFFFFF ) + ( HC >> 32u );
    uint64_t SUM_HA_L_HB_H = ( HA & 0xFFFFFFFF ) + ( HB >> 32u );

    uint64_t SUM_GC_L_GD_H = ( GC & 0xFFFFFFFF ) + ( GD >> 32u );
    uint64_t SUM_GB_L_GC_H = ( GB & 0xFFFFFFFF ) + ( GC >> 32u );
    uint64_t SUM_GA_L_GB_H = ( GA & 0xFFFFFFFF ) + ( GB >> 32u );

    uint64_t SUM_HC_L_HD_H_GD_L      = SUM_HC_L_HD_H + ( GD & 0xFFFFFFFF );
    uint64_t SUM_HB_L_HC_H_GC_L_GD_H = SUM_HB_L_HC_H + SUM_GC_L_GD_H;
    uint64_t SUM_HA_L_HB_H_GB_L_GC_H = SUM_HA_L_HB_H + SUM_GB_L_GC_H;
    uint64_t SUM_HA_H_GA_L_GB_H      = SUM_GA_L_GB_H + ( HA >> 32u );

    uint64_t SUM_HC_L_HD_H_GD_L_L       = ( SUM_HC_L_HD_H_GD_L       >> 32u ) + SUM_HB_L_HC_H_GC_L_GD_H;
    uint64_t SUM_HC_L_HD_H_GD_L_L_L     = ( SUM_HC_L_HD_H_GD_L_L     >> 32u ) + SUM_HA_L_HB_H_GB_L_GC_H;
    uint64_t SUM_HC_L_HD_H_GD_L_L_L_L   = ( SUM_HC_L_HD_H_GD_L_L_L   >> 32u ) + SUM_HA_H_GA_L_GB_H;
    uint64_t SUM_HC_L_HD_H_GD_L_L_L_L_L = ( SUM_HC_L_HD_H_GD_L_L_L_L >> 32u ) + ( GA >> 32u );

    OUT[1][0] = SUM_HC_L_HD_H_GD_L_L_L_L_L;
    OUT[1][1] = SUM_HC_L_HD_H_GD_L_L_L_L;
    OUT[1][2] = SUM_HC_L_HD_H_GD_L_L_L;
    OUT[1][3] = SUM_HC_L_HD_H_GD_L_L;
}

int main()
{
    uint32_t OUT[2][4];

    uint32_t ABCD[4] = { 4294967295u, 4294967295u, 4294967295u, 4294967295u };
    uint32_t EFGH[4] = { 4294967295u, 4294967295u, 4294967295u, 4294967295u };

    multiply128x128_1( ABCD, EFGH, OUT );

    uint64_t S_1 = 0u;
    uint64_t S_2 = 0u;
    uint64_t S_3 = 0u;
    uint64_t S_4 = 0u;
    uint64_t S_5 = 0u;

    auto start_1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    for ( uint32_t i = 0; i < ( 1 << N ); ++i )
    {
        EFGH[0] = i;
        EFGH[1] = i + X;
        EFGH[2] = i + Y;
        EFGH[3] = i + Z;

        ABCD[0] = i;
        ABCD[1] = i + X;
        ABCD[2] = i + Y;
        ABCD[3] = i + Z;

        multiply128x128( ABCD, EFGH, OUT );

        S_1 += OUT[0][0] + OUT[0][1] + OUT[0][2] + OUT[0][3];
        S_4 += OUT[1][0] + OUT[1][1] + OUT[1][2] + OUT[1][3];
    }

    auto stop_1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    std::cout << "Test A: " << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>( stop_1 - start_1 ).count() << '\n';

    auto start_3 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    for ( uint32_t i = 0; i < ( 1 << N ); ++i )
    {
        EFGH[0] = i;
        EFGH[1] = i + X;
        EFGH[2] = i + Y;
        EFGH[3] = i + Z;

        ABCD[0] = i;
        ABCD[1] = i + X;
        ABCD[2] = i + Y;
        ABCD[3] = i + Z;

        multiply128x128_1( ABCD, EFGH, OUT );

        S_3 += OUT[0][0] + OUT[0][1] + OUT[0][2] + OUT[0][3];
        S_5 += OUT[1][0] + OUT[1][1] + OUT[1][2] + OUT[1][3];
    }

    auto stop_3 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    std::cout << "Test C: " << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>( stop_3 - start_3 ).count() << '\n';

    std::cout << S_1 << " " <<  S_3 << " " << S_4 << " " <<  S_5 << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

How can i optimise my SIMD - AVX code?

Comment: Does it need to be with SIMD? The scalar version could be done in just 3 multiplies (one of them a 64x64->128 mul) and two additions, AVX is at a disadvantage E: OK I saw you have 256 bits output so it costs a little more, but still.

Comment: Well i have only avx 1.0,not avx2 instructions.  64x64 is still 3 mul?

Comment: Are you running in 32-bit mode?  x86-64 has `mul r64` which produces a 128-bit output in rdx:rax.  IIRC, gmplib doesn't use SIMD for extended-precision multiplication.  Intel introduced BMI2 `mulx` and ADX `adcx/adox` to speed extended-precision multiply by running two dep chains of additions.  That probably doesn't help you in C++, unless you can use Intel's compiler intrinsics for adcx/adox.

Comment: In GNU C++ you can use 64x64 => 128 bit multiply via `unsigned __int128`, or in MSVC with an intrinsic.  (Only on 64-bit targets, though.)  And no, compilers won't find this optimization for you.

Comment: The linked duplicate explains why scalar is a win.  (Although you do seem to be gimping yourself by not even using 64x64 => 128-bit hardware support.

Comment: BTW, `lddqu` is basically obsolete, there's no reason to use it anymore.  It just unnecessarily makes your code require SSE3 to compile.

Comment: Turns out the real problem with this code was the microbenchmark itself, which let the pure C version CSE away much of the work, as well as gimping the SIMD version with store-forwarding stalls.